# Electron Angular App, how to use native node modules

Tags: angular, webpack, electron, angular-cli

I am trying to make an electron app using angular.

I followed the tutorial  [here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/desktop-apps-with-electron-and-angular/). pretty neat work.
But I’m trying to use native node module, specifically “fs”

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as fs from 'fs';
@Injectable()
export class FilesService {

  constructor() { }

  someMethod() {
    return fs.lstat('./');
  }
}
```

and I get this error when building the app:
`ERROR in src/app/shared/files.service.ts(2,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module ‘fs’.`

After surfing the web for a while I found that it is related to the webpack config generated by angular cli, but I have no idea how to change these configurations...

Answer (score 0):

You may need adjust webpack config

1. apply correct target(https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#string)
2. apply correct `externals` to not bundle nodejs side modules.

Comment: I made the app using angular-cli, which configures webpack through angular-cli.json, is there anyway I can override webpack configs generated, or do I have to roll out my own webpack config and discard the angular-cli project ?

Comment: Ok so I used **ng eject --build** and configured webpack.config

` 
"target": "electron-renderer",
"externals": {
  "fs": require("fs")
}
`
still does not work.

Comment: nevermind everything works out fine after adding **"target": "electron-renderer"** no need to touch the externals.